# NodaTime Adding the Daylight Savings Amount to a ZonedDateTime

Tags: datetime, nodatime

I am trying to determine the correct method of adding the current amount of Daylight Savings Time to a ZonedDateTime. The following method seems to be OK, as long as the amount is a positive amount, but I wonder if there is a better method?

```
' Get the current moment in time
Dim now As Instant = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant()                                        

' Convert to UTC time
Dim UtcDateTime As ZonedDateTime = now.InUtc                                       

' Get this computer's Local TimeZone
Dim LocalTimeZone As DateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()

' Convert the UTC DateTime to the time in the Local TimeZone
Dim LocalDateTime As ZonedDateTime = UtcDateTime.WithZone(LocalTimeZone)

' The above code is just to set things up. The following code is the question:

' Check if Daylight Savings Time is in force
Dim DstInForce As Boolean = LocalDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime

' Get the Interval for the Local TimeZone
Dim LocalInterval As ZoneInterval = LocalTimeZone.GetZoneInterval(LocalDateTime.ToInstant)

' If Daylight Savings Time is in force, add the Savings Amount
If DstInForce = True Then
    LocalDateTime.PlusSeconds(CLng(LocalInterval.Savings.ToTimeSpan.TotalSeconds))    
End If
```

EDITED ADDITION..

Here is another working example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim NowDateTime As LocalDateTime = New LocalDateTime(2020, 8, 5, 9, 15)
    Dim UtcZone As DateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb("UTC")
    Dim UtcDateTime As ZonedDateTime = NowDateTime.InZoneLeniently(UtcZone)

    TextBox1.AppendText("It is currently " & UtcDateTime.ToString & " in zone " & UtcZone.ToString & vbCrLf)

    Dim ThisComputerTimeZone As DateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb("Europe/London")
    Dim ThisComputerDateTime As ZonedDateTime = UtcDateTime.WithZone(ThisComputerTimeZone)

    ' Check if Daylight Savings Time is in force
    Dim DstInForce As Boolean = ThisComputerDateTime.IsDaylightSavingTime
    Dim ThisComputerInterval As ZoneInterval = ThisComputerTimeZone.GetZoneInterval(ThisComputerDateTime.ToInstant)
    If DstInForce = True Then
        ' If Daylight Savings Time is in force, add the Savings Amount
        ThisComputerDateTime.PlusSeconds(CLng(ThisComputerInterval.Savings.ToTimeSpan.TotalSeconds))
    End If
    TextBox1.AppendText("It is currently " & ThisComputerDateTime.ToString & " in local zone " & ThisComputerTimeZone.ToString & vbCrLf)
    TextBox1.AppendText("Daylight Savings Time is '" & DstInForce & "' and has been applied." & vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

Here is its output:

```
It is currently 2020-08-05T09:15:00 UTC (+00) in zone UTC
It is currently 2020-08-05T10:15:00 Europe/London (+01) in local zone Europe/London
Daylight Savings Time is 'True' and has been applied.
```

As you can see, I needed to add the extra Savings amount to change the UTC time '09:15' to the Daylight Savings time '10:15'. What am I trying to do? I am trying to create a UTC time, then change it to the local time of my computer, with the correct DST amount included. These steps are part of a larger process, abbreviated for clarity.

Comment: Firstly, I'd *really, really* strongly suggest that you don't give a variable of type `ZonedDateTime` a name of `LocalDateTime`. That's *really* confusing when `LocalDateTime` is another type. It's like declaring a `String` variable with a name of `Integer`. But beyond that, it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. The `ZonedDateTime` will already be taking account of DST. Why would you add it a *second* time? Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have edited my example to include a working example of the code. I need, for other reasons, to start with UTC, then convert that to another timezone, with DST taken into account.

Comment: I see you've removed the "accepted answer" - please could you let me know if there's something that's still not working?

Comment: I'm not sure why that was removed. Yes, all is good now. I really appreciate you taking the time to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any of the code after "Check if Daylight Savings Time is in force" - it's already taken into account by the `WithZone` method. Your code isn't actually doing anything useful anyway because you're ignoring the result of `PlusSeconds` - that doesn't modify the existing `ZonedDateTime`, it returns a new one.

This line:

```vb
Dim ThisComputerDateTime As ZonedDateTime = UtcDateTime.WithZone(ThisComputerTimeZone)
```

... does all that you need it to. `WithZone` takes daylight saving time into account already. There's no need to try to manually adjust it.